# Error occurred while enabling [Plugin] v1.0 (is it up to date)

Tags: java

so i've been trying to code my own plugins and i just figured out why they never showed up in my /plugins (it was from a yml error) but in logs it said "Error occurred while enabling deathswap v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke" Can you guys help? I've always wanted to play deathswap and i spent a good amount of time coding it,, I've tried searching on google but no one answered the question in general.

Full Error Log:

```
[12:06:44] [Worker-Main-4/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[12:06:45] [Worker-Main-4/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[12:06:45] [Worker-Main-5/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[12:06:46] [Worker-Main-4/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 1%
[12:06:46] [Worker-Main-4/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 40%
[12:06:47] [Worker-Main-4/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 74%
[12:06:47] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 91%
[12:06:47] [Server thread/INFO]: Time elapsed: 3169 ms
[12:06:47] [Server thread/INFO]: [deathswap] Enabling deathswap v1.0
[12:06:47] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling deathswap v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.setExecutor(org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor)" because the return value of "me.Rayne.DeathSwap.Main.getCommand(String)" is null
    at me.Rayne.DeathSwap.commands.SwapCommand.<init>(SwapCommand.java:21) ~[?:?]
    at me.Rayne.DeathSwap.Main.onEnable(Main.java:12) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot-1.17.jar:3159-Spigot-f773da8-887bc05]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:342) ~[spigot-1.17.jar:3159-Spigot-f773da8-887bc05]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot-1.17.jar:3159-Spigot-f773da8-887bc05]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:495) ~[spigot-1.17.jar:3159-Spigot-f773da8-887bc05]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:409) ~[spigot-1.17.jar:3159-Spigot-f773da8-887bc05]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:608) ~[spigot-1.17.jar:3159-Spigot-f773da8-887bc05]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:264) ~[spigot-1.17.jar:3159-Spigot-f773da8-887bc05]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.x(MinecraftServer.java:987) ~[spigot-1.17.jar:3159-Spigot-f773da8-887bc05]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:307) ~[spigot-1.17.jar:3159-Spigot-f773da8-887bc05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to add entry about your command in `plugin.yml`. E.g.:

```
commands:
  command_name:
     description: Your command description
     usage: /<command>
     permission: your.command.permission
```

More info on Spigot [wiki page](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/#commands)